# Laravel Dynamic DB Relation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-6

I didn't find any solution so i am asking it here..

```
Match.php 
id , teams           name
1    5,6(string)   kkr vs mi
Team.php 
id  name 
5   kkr
6   mi
```

The id of Team is related with teams in Match ,for this the solution is easy.. but The Problem is that one Match can have 3/4+ no of teams So i have to make it dynamic ...

Comment: An easiest solutions will be to bring pivot table in your Database.
For example *team_matches* with `id`, `team_id`, `match_id` and get all relations via *hasManyThrough*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Per @maki10 The working Solution Is

```
public function teams() {
      return $this->hasManyThrough(
         'App\model\Team',
         'App\model\MatchTeam',
         'match_id',
         'id',
         'id',
         'team_id'
      );
    }
```